# How do you carry out your task

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I want to understand how to use the phrasal verb "carry out"

So my question is, Can I ask

> How do you carry out your task? Which tools do you use?

and can I ask:

> Do you still carry out your test?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read through our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners), where you'll learn some helpful tips for formatting questions, like using "I" (not "i"), and how to insert line breaks and quote boxes.

Answer (score 1):

**Carry out** means to bring to a successful issue, complete or accomplish, or to continue to an end or stopping point ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carryout)).

Example:

> He carried out the task efficiently and cheerfully.

You can't say:

> Do you still carry out your test?

...because "carry out" refers to *perform and complete,* not only to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you carry out a task, you do/perform the task:

> I left her to carry out the task of correcting the errors.

You can also carry out a test:

> Rigorous safety tests are being carried out (= conducted/performed/run) on the new jet.